# how to change the XML structure using XQuery

Tags: xquery, basex

I have a XML file containing Employees Name and the Job done by them.
The structure of the XML file is -

```
<Employee>AAA@A#B#C#D</Employee>
<Employee>BBB@A#B#C#D</Employee>
<Employee>CCC@A#B#C#D</Employee>
<Employee>DDD@A#B#C#D</Employee>
```

There are thousands of records and I have to change structure to -

```
<Employee>
  <Name>AAA</Name>
  <Jobs>
   <Job>A</Job>
   <Job>B</Job>
   <Job>C</Job>
   <Job>D</Job>
  </Jobs>
</Employee>
```

How to get this done using XQuery in BaseX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 XQuery functions, `substring-before`, `substring-after` and `tokenize` are used to get 
the required output.

`substring-before` is used to get the Name.

Similarly, the `substring-after` is used to get the Job portion.

Then the `tokenize` function, is used to split the Jobs.

```
let $data :=
  <E>
    <Employee>AAA@A#B#C#D</Employee>
    <Employee>BBB@A#B#C#D</Employee>
    <Employee>CCC@A#B#C#D</Employee>
    <Employee>DDD@A#B#C#D</Employee>
  </E>


for $x in $data/Employee
return 

<Employee>
   {<Name>{substring-before($x,"@")}</Name>}
   {<Jobs>{
   for $tag in tokenize(substring-after($x,"@"),'#')
   return 
     <Job>{$tag}</Job>
   }</Jobs>
}</Employee>
```

HTH...

Answer (score 2):

Tokenizing the string is probably easier and faster. `tokenize($string, $pattern)` splits `$string` using the regular expression `$pattern`, `head($seq)` returns the first value of a sequence and `tail($seq)` all but the first. You could also use positional predicates of course, but these functions are easier to read.

```
for $employee in //Employee
let $tokens := tokenize($employee, '[@#]')
return element Employee {
  element Name { head($tokens) },
  element Jobs {
    for $job in tail($tokens)
    return element Job { $job }
  }
}
```